# Multiple DataGrids on one DataTable

Tags: datagrid, datatable, wpfdatagrid, collectionviewsource

I've got two `CollectionViewSource` bindings to the same data table `Client`. Each `CollectionViewSource` has a separate `DataGrid` binded to it:

```
(dg1: DataGrid) ----> (cvs1: CollectionViewSource) ----
                                                      |
                                                      v
                                                (Clients: DataTable)
                                                      ^
                                                      |
(dg2: DataGrid) ----> (cvs2: CollectionViewSource) ----
```

Or in XAML:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs1" Source="{Binding Client, Source={StaticResource MainDataSet}}"/>
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs2" Source="{Binding Client, Source={StaticResource MainDataSet}}"/>
...
...
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs1}}" ...>
    ....
</DataGrid>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs2}}" ...>
    ....
</DataGrid>
```

However when the application runs and I click on the first `DataGrid` to sort by some column, the second `DataGrid` is instantly sorted identically and together with the first one. This is not what I want.

As far as I know each `CollectionViewSource` should have its own view of the data, so am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still looking for a solution but I had the same issue. It's solved by creating a new CollectionViewSource. In essence it's as such:

ICollectionView cvs1= new CollectionViewSource { Source = dataSource }.View;
ICollectionView cvs2= new CollectionViewSource { Source = dataSource }.View;

This will allow you to have individual views.